# How to create a special folder for windows app iin file explorer like Onedrive or Dropbox does

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, desktop-application, microsoft-file-explorer

Iam developing a desktop app for windows using electronJs, Iam planning to place it as a special folder underneath the quick access in file explorer like the way how Onedrive and Dropbox does, but couldn't find how they did with their apps, is there any suggestion to place them programmatically

sample:

[image]

Comment: What should this folder contain? Are you a real cloud storage?

Comment: Later, I came to know, what Iam looking for is a shell extension (Shell Folder) and I want to create a cloud sync engine basically, that transfer files between the remote and client. any suggestion on how to develop that

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud Sync Engines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/cloud-files-api-portal) on MSDN should get you started. The namespace folder registration documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/integrate-cloud-storage).